# Who resized my view? (on iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Using the Empty App template on Xcode 4.3.2, a project is created, so there is no NIB involved.

In `FooViewController.m`:

```
-(void) loadView {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    self.view = view;                     
}
```

So a view is instantiated and assigned to `self.view`.  The two methods:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"self.view is %@", self.view);
}

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"self.view is %@", self.view);
}
```

The first method will print out

```
self.view is <UIView: 0x18e4d0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x182a00>>
```

while the second one prints out

```
self.view is <UIView: 0x18e4d0; frame = (0 20; 768 1004); layer = <CALayer: 0x182a00>>
```

So between `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`, the view is resized.  What is the mechanism that resized it?  Can we actually count on it?  Because even Matt Neuburg, the author of the highly regarded book Programming iOS, 2nd Ed, is doing it this way (as on page 508).

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand the ViewController lifecycle.
In viewDidLoad the views will be created but the boundaries/dimensions won't be set. That will  happen in a following step. You can use viewWillAppear for setting dimensions (what most people do). ViewDidAppear happens last, and there you already have the final appearance and the animations already started.

So yeah, between viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear, the view gets its dimension and boundaries, it's totally reliable and also documented in the ViewController  docs.

Notice also that viewDidLoad will be called every time the views need to be created (like first time and after a low memory warning -views are usually deallocated when memory is needed-) and viewWillAppear will be called every time a view controller is on top of the stack and its views are about to be rendered.

Have a look at the documentation related to view appearance: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDisplay-Notifications/RespondingtoDisplay-Notifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH12

Comment: that seems right... however if an empty method `viewWillAppear` is defined to override the default behavior, the view is still resized...

Comment: 100+ pages of ViewController Programming Guide... you can't say iOS isn't well documented...

Comment: That is why I suggested using a container view. Working with self.view directly is kind of a pain, like the x, y dimensions will always stay the same, even when the display flips. It is a special view because the OS makes changes to that view directly. You are better off having a view as a subview of self.view

Comment: @mjb162 for the flip issue, if you use `bounds` instead of `frame`, you shouldn't have that issue

Comment: @動靜能量, I designed a custom splitViewController and it plagued me from the beginning using that as the main view. However, I did not know the bounds vs frame difference, that may have made things easier. It was just a mess having several views inside of a view that did not actually flip, just under went a linear transformation. Doing the animation and making sure they hit the right places, such a pain. So I would still advocate the use of a subview, that made my life easier in almost all occasions.

Comment: I did'nt say that the dimensions and bounds are set in the viewWillAppear method. What I said is that you can use that method to change them. Probably, the "default" values for a view are set in some private api/method and depends whether you are loading from a NIB or not.

Comment: @monzonj so this project has no NIB at all... then what you mean is that it is some where...  the question of this post is basically ask where...  by the way in `viewWillAppear`, the size is already set, so it is some where between `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear`

Comment: @動靜能量 look at my answer again. I go into more detail about specifically what is going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the [`autoresizesSubviews`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizesSubviews) property will cause a view to resize its subviews when it is displayed.

Comment: if I add `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].autoresizesSubviews = NO;` to the end of `viewDidLoad`, the view is still resized

Answer (score 0):

self.view is not actually created until it is shown on screen. It is lazy loaded. After `viewWillAppear` is called, the frame will be set. Yes, you can trust those values because they are being set according to the screen and orientation of the phone.

self.view is a rather special view, I often do not work with it directly, I usually just add a container subview and treat that as the primary view. Because of the resizing, it is best to not treat self.view as a static entity. Make sure to set your subview's autoresizing masks appropriately so they will be displayed properly when self.view changes.

To further answer you question, UIKit specifically sets the view's frame to take into account the screen's size, orientation, navigation bars, status bar, tool bar, etc. You are not guaranteed that that the frame you set prior to `viewWillAppear` being called, will be the same. In fact, self.view will change even more if navigation bars, orientation, or other factors change. So even after `viewWillDisplay` you are not guaranteed a static size for self.view and if you change it, it will be reset appropriately to reflect that status of the device.

UIKit takes care of this implementation detail for us, it is a luxury because then we do not have to take into account device specific changes, just make sure autoresizing of subviews is set up appropriately and UIKit takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `viewController`'s `view` is resized **when you make this `viewController` a `rootViewController` of `application`'s `window`**. Otherwise you have to set it's frame manually.

I tried this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    FooViewController *viewController = [[FooViewController alloc] init];

    self.window.rootViewController = viewController; 
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    FooViewController *viewController2 = [[FooViewController alloc] init];
    [viewController.view addSubview: [viewController2 view]];

    return YES;
}
```

`viewController` was resized and `viewController2` was not.

Also: for `viewController` all this methods were called:

```
viewDidLoad
viewWillLayoutSubviews
viewDidLayoutSubviews
viewDidAppear
```

for `viewController2` only `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` were called.

Also interesting: `viewController` was resized before it's `viewWillLayoutSubviews` was called.

EDIT:

I figured this is worth further testing. Using the following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    FooViewController *viewController = [[FooViewController alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"after init: self.view is %@", viewController.view);
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController; 
    NSLog(@"after setting to rootViewController: self.view is %@", viewController.view);
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    NSLog(@"after makeKeyAndVisible: self.view is %@", viewController.view);

    return YES;
}
```

results were:

```
viewDidLoad:                         frame = (0 0; 0 0)
after init:                          frame = (0 0; 0 0)
after setting to rootViewController: frame = (0 0; 0 0)
after makeKeyAndVisible:             frame = (0 20; 320 460)
viewWillLayoutSubviews:              frame = (0 20; 320 460)
viewDidLayoutSubviews:               frame = (0 20; 320 460)
viewDidAppear:                       frame = (0 20; 320 460)
```

So **`[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`** is the culprit.